# How can I add animation (via getKeyFrame) to scene2d actor

Tags: android, animation, scene2d

I'm using libgdx and scene2d for an android game. I have a stage with actors that can be clicked on to perform various tasks. The actors are currently static images. I have other code that does targeting overlays with

```
    targetRingSmall = new Animation(1 / 6f, targetAtlas.findRegions("small"));
    targetRingSmall.setPlayMode(Animation.LOOP_PINGPONG);
    targetRingSmall.getKeyFrame(0);
```

and

```
animationTime += delta;
batch.draw(targetRingSmall.getKeyFrame(animationTime), x, y, 76, 76);
```

I want to change the actors to be looping animated images while keeping them as clickable actors. How can I do that?

Comment: Can u post some graphical representation of what you trying to do?

Comment: I'm currently just using square boxes as placeholder graphics. I want to replace them with animated sprites. I listed the getKeyFrame coded as an example of how I'm doing animations of non-actor objects.

Answer (score 1):

Using setDrawable on the actor with the keyframe image of the animation works for what I needed.